When labeling, "Wrap on character" drops the wrap character
At 3.34.8, I have a polygon layer field containing the names of numerous Wilderness Areas, such as:
Sierra de las Uvas Wilderness
Broad Canyon Wilderness
I would like to label these polygons so that the text is split over two lines, with the word Wilderness on the second line, as in:
Sierra de las Uvas
    Wilderness
Broad Canyon
  Wilderness
The obvious solution seemed to be Layer Styling > Labels > Formatting > Wrap on character, and wrap on the letter 'W'.  But when I tried that, the 'W' was dropped so that the labels looked like:
Sierra de las Uvas
    ilderness
Broad Canyon
  ilderness
I'm surprised that Wrap on character drops the character!
This seems like a bug, but if not, how can I force the word 'Wilderness' to a new line?
Perhaps another way to frame the question: How to wrap on a word?

You could also hardcode the line break into your attribute itself, using wordwrap(). You need to hand it a number after which to wrap the text. A positive number provides a ceiling of characters after which to wrap, a negative number provides a floor.
In your case you could just try some numbers and hopefully get a satisfactory result, or you could also use strpos() in order to find the place in the string where the wilderness begins.
strpos(field_with_wilderness_labels, 'Wilderness') returns you that place. Now hand this result to wordwrap and enjoy:
wordwrap(field_with_wilderness_labels,strpos(field_with_wilderness_labels, 'Wilderness'))
See picture for result, I labeled by label 2.

As a side note you could also leave your attributes untouched and use the expression including either the asteriks or the wordwrap solution themselves as expression to label the areas by.

All of the answers will work just fine, but I like your wordwrap solution the best because it does not require an additional attribute field.

Generally the tool is used with special characters that are designated as word wrap characters, like an asterisk:
*
But you can do the same for Wilderness. Just add a character infront of the key word. Make you label:
replace(field_with_wilderness_labels, 'Wilderness', '*Wilderness')

Then Wrap on character *

Another option; insert a line break \nbefore Wilderness:
replace("name", 'Wilderness', '\nWilderness') and dont use Wrap on character:


Just to add another possibility that might be helpful in more complex cases as you can freely rearrange different parts of a string. Use Regular Expressions with regexp_matches as input for the label setting. The following expression splits the input string in two parts:

A: everything (string of any length) that is not Wilderness
B: followed by the string Wilderness

It then rearranges these two parts with a linebreak in between, using index operator [], where [0] is the first element (A).
with_variable(
    'strings',
    regexp_matches(
        name,
        '(.* )(Wilderness)'
    ),
    @strings[0] || '\n' || @strings[1]
)

